# Find the distribution of $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ where X and Y are normally distributed.

Tags: probability-distributions

Find the distribution of $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent normally distributed $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

What is the best way to go about this? I tried finding the distribution of $X^2$ and $Y^2$ and then adding the two distributions, but this results in an undefined integral.

Or do we let $U=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ and $V=X$ and then find the joint distribution of $U$ and $V$ and then find the marginal distribution of $U$?

I have the answer I am meant to reach; just can't get there.

Comment: Are X and Y independent?

Comment: Yes they are, sorry forgot to mention that

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
F_z(z) = \mathbb{P}[X^2+Y^2\leq R^2]&=&\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq R^2}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\,dx\,dy \\
&=& \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}\rho e^{-\rho^2/2}\,d\rho\,d\theta = 1 - e^{-R^2/2}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

hence the distribution of $Z=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ has a probability density function supported on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and given by:
$$f_Z(z)=z\, e^{-z^2/2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $X=R\cos A$ and $Y=R\sin A$ where $R>0$ and $A\in (0,2\pi)$. You want to find the distribution of $R$.

So the Jacobian turns out to be $r$.

So the joint distribution of $R$ and $A$ is $$f_{R,A}(r,a)=\dfrac{r}{2\pi}e^{\dfrac{-r^2}{2}}$$.Note that $R$ and $A$ are independent.

Integrate out $A$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ to obtain the marginal of $R$ as $f_R(r)=re^\dfrac{-r^2}{2}$ where $r>0$

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn't have thought about using a polar transformation.

Comment: I remember when I faced this question for the first time, just a month ago. :) I tried this method and it worked !! :) Your method will also work but the steps will be messy.

Comment: By the way, adding $X^2$ and $Y^2$ gives you the very famous chi-square distribution, whose root is something you will find difficult to find, probably.