# Probability distribution function of $x^n+y^n$ when $x,y$ are normally distributed?

Tags: probability-distributions

Say I have two random variables, $x,y$ that are independent and normally distributed, $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. What is the probability distribution function of $r$ and $r^2$ where $r=\sqrt{x^n+y^n}$ and $n$ is a positive even integer? It is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1212807) that for $n=2$ we get a Rayleigh distribution for $r$, but can something be said for higher values of $n$?